# python package installation gives "error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"

Tags: python, gcc, numpy, installation

I'm trying to install a python package called `mlabwrap-1.1` on Ubuntu, with python2.7. However, the installation fails and reports:

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Note: A while back I updated numpy and got a bunch of warnings, but I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

So what could be the problem?

### Some details

Linux version 3.2.0-49-generic (buildd@komainu) (gcc version 4.6.3
(Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 18 17:39:32 UTC 2013

### The exact error I get:

```
[r@b ~/local/mlabwrap-1.1]$ sudo python setup.py install

running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'mlabrawmodule' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -D_V6_5_OR_LATER=1 -I/usr/local/matlab/extern/include -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c mlabraw.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/mlabraw.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1804:0,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from mlabraw.cpp:136:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
mlabraw.cpp: In function ‘PyArrayObject* mx2numeric(const mxArray*)’:
mlabraw.cpp:225:34: error: cannot convert ‘const mwSize* {aka const long unsigned int*}’ to ‘const int*’ in assignment
mlabraw.cpp: In function ‘mxArray* makeMxFromNumeric(const PyArrayObject*)’:
mlabraw.cpp:365:93: error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘const mwSize* {aka const long unsigned int*}’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘mxArray* mxCreateNumericArray(mwSize, const mwSize*, mxClassID, mxComplexity)’
mlabraw.cpp: In function ‘mxArray* numeric2mx(PyObject*)’:
mlabraw.cpp:509:54: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
mlabraw.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* mlabraw_open(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
mlabraw.cpp:570:16: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
mlabraw.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* mlabraw_eval(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
mlabraw.cpp:631:15: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
mlabraw.cpp:662:66: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
mlabraw.cpp: In function ‘void initmlabraw()’:
mlabraw.cpp:895:65: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had this before and needed to install libevent-dev.

```
apt-get install libevent-dev
```

I have no way to check this now, but it's worth a try I think.

Answer (score 0):

You are installing a python packages that requires a C extension, so it needs at least a C compiler like gcc. Now in the specific case of numpy i'd suggest to use the packaged one *apt-get install python-numpy*, but if for some reason you don't want to do that i'd install all the required packages with *apt-get build-dep python-numpy* and then rerun the install. Since you look like a python newbie i'd suggest you to start using a virtualenv instead of installing libraries globally.